# unity mesh collider not in the same position as the object

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

I'm currently learning Unity and I want to import a 3D model to my scene (.FBX)

I use mesh collider for detecting collision, but the collider's position is not the same as my 3D object. The mesh's position is above the object and I can't move it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On imported objects you have two tranforms, one for the game object and the other for the mesh. The mesh's transform is relative to its parent game object and thus should be (0, 0, 0) in most cases:

[image: mesh-collider-test]

Mesh colliders are pretty CPU expensive and should be used for simple static objects only. If you have a more complex model, you should consider using a simpler collider.